# Sybase ASE: Optimizing a query with multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, sybase, sap-ase

I have a large table (large_table, 6M+ rows) with indexed columns

- id primary key
- small_ref_id (integer) references the primary  key of a small table (small_table, 2k+ rows)
- mid_ref_id (integer) references the primary key of a medium table (mid_table, 200k+ rows)
- The data of small_table is divided by groups of data that are named in the indexed column group_name (varchar).
- The data of mid_table is divided by types of data that are named in the indexed column type (varchar).
- The large table has 2 indexed timestamps (date_time1,date_time2).
- The medium table has 1 indexed timestamp (date_time3).

My query looks like :

```
select * from large_table, mid_table, small_table 
where large_table.small_ref_id=small_table.id
and large_table.mid_ref_id=mid_table.id
and small_table.group_name='MyGroup'
and 
   (large_table.id in (select large_table.id from large_table, mid_table
where mid_table.id=large_table.mid_ref_id 
and large_table.date_time1 between '2010-01-01' and '2017-01-01' 
and mid_table.type='Type1')
or large_table.id in (select large_table.id from large_table, mid_table 
where mid_table.id=large_table.mid_ref_id 
and large_table.date_time2 between '2010-06-01' and '2017-01-01' 
and mid_table.type='Type2')
or large_table.id in (select large_table.id from large_table, mid_table 
where mid_table.id=large_table.mid_ref_id 
and mid_table.date_time3 between '2010-08-01' and '2017-01-01' 
and mid_table.type='Type3'))
```

It can take several minutes (<5min) to fetch the results.

What I tried :

- Spliting the query by small_ref_id into as many queries as ids inside 'MyGroup', running in parallel (using a thread pool inside the application, with a fixed number of workers) : This resulted in no improvement, plus taking 100% of database CPU.
- Replacing the "large_table.id in (select id from large_table" with "exists (select 1 from large_table t where t.id=large_table.id" : This also resulted into no improvement.

Any ideas ?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Can you share the query plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you don't need subqueries. You can just apply the three conditions to the `large_table` and `mid_table` data you already have from the main query:

```
select     * 
from       large_table 
inner join mid_table
        on large_table.mid_ref_id = mid_table.id
inner join small_table 
        on large_table.small_ref_id = small_table.id
       and small_table.group_name = 'MyGroup'
where      (
                (large_table.date_time1 between '2010-01-01' and '2017-01-01' 
                 and mid_table.type = 'Type1')
            or
                (large_table.date_time2 between '2010-06-01' and '2017-01-01' 
                 and mid_table.type = 'Type2')
            or  
                (mid_table.date_time3 between '2010-08-01' and '2017-01-01' 
                 and mid_table.type = 'Type3')
           )
```

As a side note: use the [`inner join` syntax](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X25432.htm).

NB: Are you sure about the last condition? It tests on `mid_table.date_time3` while the other two conditions take their date from `large_table`...

Comment: what is the effect of not using the inner join syntax ?

Comment: There should be no difference in the efficiency of the query. It is just a syntax choice. But putting the join conditions in the `where` clause is so ... eighties? Here is a [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.